# Replace content in default view with some other specific view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a simplified version of my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>foo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!---replace me-->
   </body>
</html>
```

This is one of my views (`app/views/home/about.html.erb`):

```
<h1>About</h1>
```

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` then I get `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

I want to know how to fill the body of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (`<!---replace me-->`) to be filled with `app/views/home/about.html.erb`.  I think my `config/routes.rb` is fine?:

```
match '/about/' => 'home#about'
```

but the problem is that when I click 'About', the contents of 'About' get **appended** to the default view.  I don't want it appended.. I want `<!--replace me-->` replaced with `<h1>About</h1>`.

Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the 'replace me' comment with `<%= yield %>`. It will insert the appropriate view.

And as long as you have a home controller with an about action this route will work:

```
match '/about',  to: 'home#about'
```

hope this gets you started